# Writing a rule for parser

Tags: c, parsing, grammar, yacc, rule

Hii,

I have a parser which has many rules and no problem with it its all working.. i am using lex and yacc...

The problem is i want a rule such that if the input string does not match any of the rules defined in the parser then i want to write a rule which will accept such input string..

So basically what i want to do is that i dont want the parser to stop give an error message on itself if the input does not match any other rule, i want to display that error message and then make the parser continue its parsing instead of exiting..

I kno i have to make changes in yyerror() function but how exactly.. or is there any other i can write such a rule...

Thanks.. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can place the "." (dot) at the end of other parsing rules. It matches any string that has not matched by other rules. See this [link](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/zvm/v5r3/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.zvm.v53.dmsp4/hcsp4b1035.htm) for details.

Hope, it's what you meant.

**Edit:** It seams I have misunderstood. To define default action you can simply put `{ }` action in the parser file. See [here](http://luv.asn.au/overheads/lex_yacc/yacc.html#default_action).

Comment: I think what you linked to is for tokenizing, not parsing.

Comment: Thanks for those links it was helpful.. Problem is solved.. :) :)